# How did Jamal get into the game show?

Tags: plot-explanation, slumdog-millionaire

In ***Slumdog Millionaire***, how did Jamal managed to get into the game show?

I can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Jamal used to supply tea in a call center.

A person working in this call center says that the telephone lines to answer the question that the host just asked are opened when he reaches a particular word in his dialogue.

Jamal follows this tip and manages to make a call and then answer the question correctly. He got selected and made an entry in the game.

Comment: So it was partially luck, right? Unless (as with removing fastest finger first) they altered the rules for getting in to early callers.

Comment: @Almo Arguably 'yes', though the movie has a strong motif of predestination, so in once sense 'no'.